# Resources for Ruby ActiveRecords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and wanted to learn more in-depth about active records
library. Where should I start from? Are there any printed/online
books/resources I can look through?

I came across to "Pro Active Record: Databases with Ruby and Rails" book
authored by Kevin Marshall, Chad Pytel and Jon Yurek. But that seems to
be quite old(2007 edition).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Official Rails Guides documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) is a good place to start. All four chapters under the `Model` section will be useful.

In addition check out this useful introduction blogpost (with screencast videos) by Richard Schneeman : [Active Record Deep Dive](http://schneems.com/post/28125445535/active-record-deep-dive)

Comment: Sure, I will look into this. But I guess I need some more in-depth resources. Hope I could get some.

Answer (score 1):

Rails guide is one of the best place to learn rails. Below few links that will helps you.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I was looking for some more in-depth resources.